# Gradle location is incorrect error while importing ActionBarsherlock in Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I'm also trying to import the ABS in new updated Android Studio.
I'm following [this](http://armanpagilagan.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-actionbarsherlock-in-android.html) tutorial.

but on step **Adding Action Bar Sherlock library to Android Studio** im getting the error

Gradle Location is incorrect. here is pic.

[image]

When I go to the path `C:\Users\Sir John Qadir\` there is no any gradle1.6 folder in there. How to resolve this?

Comment: install gradle and point it at that folder ...

Comment: where to install from it and is it not installed along with andorid studio intallation?

Comment: it will automatically get installed from internet while creating your first project. After that you can set the gradle as local path from gradle settings under File>Settings > Gradle.

Comment: [How to set gradle home while importing existing project in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21646252/6521116)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try using this path:

***For Windows***

```
C:\Users\MyHome\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\<some random folder>\gradle-1.6
```

***For UNIX (Debian, Mac etc.)***

```
~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-<a-version>-<bin or all>/<some random folder>/gradle-<a-version>
```

Comment: `~\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-<a-version>-<bin or all>\<some random folder>\gradle-<a-version>` for mac users

Comment: Im using `/Users/vito/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b/gradle-2.2.1/` in my MacBook, thanks for solved my problem. ; )

Comment: What will be "some random folder" ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know where that random folder is supposed to come from either.

Comment: This is not necessarily the solution for Mac (see answer below)

Answer (score 154):

If you have installed your gradle with brew then it would be:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/<version>/libexec/
```

Comment: This is the real answer! which path the IDE required? that's it!

Comment: This answer is the one that worked for me for IntelliJ! Lifesaver.

Answer (score 37):

Point to the folder `<gradle root folder>/libexec`. Things should start working.

Answer (score 23):

When using homebrew, instead of (as suggested in other answers):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/<version>/libexec/
```

It's better to use:

```
/usr/local/opt/gradle/libexec
```

It's a symlink and will survive `brew upgrade`.

Answer (score 8):

Create a build.gradle with:

```
task getHomeDir << {
    println gradle.gradleHomeDir
}
```

Then run it with:

```
gradle getHomeDir
```

You should see something like:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/1.6/libexec
```

You can use that to populate the Gradle plugin, and you’re off.

http://www.rabblemedia.net/blog/setting-up-gradle-plugin-for-intellij/

Answer (score 5):

If you use brew to install gradle on mac, then use /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.0.1/libexec