# Gradle: download gradle takes "very long time", activity_main.xml keeps showing "Loading"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have installed Android Studio today. I'm a newbie to Android development. I know that it has been asked several times, but my Android Studio is **most updated** as of now, so none of the solution seems to work. **[AndroidStudio v3.6]**

After the installation got over, I attempted to create an Empty Project. It opened the whole project as seen below,

[image]

After waiting for 7+ minutes (bottom-left), gradle is still not downloaded, and the `activity_main.xml` file keeps showing "Loading".

### [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623439) - Change the gradle location

I found this location to `C:\Users\RAHUL.LAPTOP-DISIIAS2\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.4-all\ankdp27end7byghfw1q2sw75f`, but it contains two files - one is `gradle-5.6.4-all.zip.part` and other is `gradle-5.6.4-all.zip.lck` file.

### [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443741) - Invalidate and restart

Doesn't seem to work

### [Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391421) - Change gradle settings to work in offline mode

The version I'm using doesn't have the option

[image]

How can I fix it?

---

Here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

[image]

Comment: Hi Rahul. Please try to keep your questions succinct if you can. While readers appreciate you might be desperate, appeals to sympathy ("please help me", "I have been stuck for hours") are not relevant to the problem at hand, and readers do not want to be nagged.

Comment: @halfer, thanks for editing the post (shaka)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check if you are connected to `services.gradle.org` with `ping` command in Command Prompt. If you are connected, then change Proxy Settings in Android Studio to `Use System Proxy`. If it is downloading slowly again, your internet connection may be slow. Or you best fallow guidelines in this link : [Gradle Download: Installing Manually](https://gradle.org/install/#manually)

Then work in offline mode will appear in your settings.

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me the most. I did downloaded the file from `http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` (distributionUrl) manually. And, then placed it insode `C:\Users\RAHUL.LAPTOP-DISIIAS2\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.4-all\ankdp27end7byghfw1q2sw75f`. Finally, I toggled gradle to work in offline mode by clicking gradle tab at top-right corner and then pressing `–//–` button. After that, the message changed from "downloading gradle" to "building gradle". It took almost 10-15 minutes for me to start with Android Studio from there. That's my gradle story! :)

Comment: Afarin Afarin, Work as a charm